# Change one specific byte of an IP address

Tags: esp8266

So if I have an IP address `IP Address: 192.64.5.1`, is it somehow possible to change a specific byte of that IP to like `IP Address: 192.64.**6**.1`

My idea is to change the IP Address into variables `IP Address: a.b.c.d`
Now I could say `a= 192; b= 64; c= 5 + 1; d= 1`

But what if I receive the `IP Address: 192.64.5.1` as a String. Is it somehow possible to split it up into 4 parts that I can each individually assign to an integer (a, b, c or d)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it all with the `IPAddress` class.

For instance: create an IP address from a string:

```
IPAddress myAddr(myString);
```

Create a new IP address with one byte changed:

```
IPAddress myNewAddr(myAddr[0], myAddr[1], myAddr[2] + 1, myAddr[3]);
```

Comment: and `myAddr[2] = 6`. `myAddr[2]+=1` or `myAddr[2]++` works too

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can split the string with the C library function `strtok`, than concatenate everything together with your own string with the C library `strcat`.
You can convert strings to `atoi`, so use the resulting string from strtok with atoi to an integer.

Tip: try it on a PC with a local C compiler, because you can check it very fast (unless you can implement it first time right). Than you copy it to your Arduino sketch. Make sure to start with a char buffer big enough for the biggest possible IP address string.